# Lowdb: pop the first inserted item from array

Tags: javascript, lowdb

I am using [lowdb](https://github.com/typicode/lowdb) to pop an object from a list

```
{
  "posts": [
    { "id": a, "title": "lowdb is awesome"},
    { "id": b, "title": "lowdb is awesome"},
    { "id": c, "title": "lowdb is awesome"}
  ],
  "user": {
    "name": "typicode"
  },
  "count": 3
}
```

and need to figure out how to "pop" the first inserted object from posts:

```
db.get('posts')
  .find()
  .value()
```

which I expect to return `{ "id": a, "title": "lowdb is awesome"}` and the posts will reflect this

Answer (score 0):

removing the first item in an array can simply be done by using `shift()` method. Note that `pop()` removes the last item in the array.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the first item from an array, [you need to use](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) `shift()`.

This will remove the first item from the array, and return it.

To explain how `shift()` works, try running the code below:

```js
let a = [ {"a":1}, {"b":2}, {"c":3} ];

// Prints [ {"a":1}, {"b":2}, {"c":3} ]
console.log(a);

// This line will remove the top item from a
// and store it in topItem
let topItem = a.shift();

// Prints {"a":1}
console.log(topItem);

// Prints [ {"b":2}, {"c":3} ]
console.log(a);
```